# Selenium WebDriver - Highlight all web elements in the solution

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I would like to highlight EVERY single web element during test run (Clicked etc). 
The majority of options are similar to the one below which requires 
to assign the highlight action to each web element **individually**.

```
IWebElement element = urrentWebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='ID']"));
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)currentWebDriver;

js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);", element, " border: 3px solid red;");
```

Is there a way to enable element highlight collectively ? 
Can that be done via [SetUp] (I'm using Nunit) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve your problem by creating your own findElement function. Simply before returning element, highlight it using javascript.
Instead of calling the **driver.findElement**, call your own findElement function that is doing the same and also highlighting the element.

```
public WebElement findElement(By by) {
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(by);

    if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.border='3px solid red'", element);
    }
    return element;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It maybe worthwhile to write an extension method to FindElement using that

Comment: if you got your solution kindly accept the answer so others can get benefit from it :).